# In ear headphones for stealth street recording

Tags: field, stealth, recording, recommendations

Hi everybody

I've been looking into getting a pair of good in ear headphones, preferably providing decent isolation. This is to use with handheld recorders, if possible to avoid people asking stuff like "are you recording sound?" or "are you looking for radiation?". I'm sure all of you have been there tons of times :D
What do you guys use for this? Under 150€/180$ would be nice
I've been looking into the [SHURE SCL2-K](http://www.thomann.de/gb/shure_scl2k.htm)

[Shure SCL2-K http://images1.thomann.de/pics/prod/119528.jpg](http://www.thomann.de/gb/shure_scl2k.htm)

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I love my IE30s and IE 40s made by Ultimate Ears (distributed by M-audio).

Really cool design because they use armature drivers instead of traditional drivers.  My IE40s are nearly as accurate (frequency wise) as my Beyerdynamics.  I can't say that sound quite as good spatially, but you'll lose that with any in-ear solution.

[image]
<sub>(source: [m-audio.com](http://www.m-audio.com/images/global/product_pics/th/IE_40custom_parts_big.jpg))</sub>

[image]
<sub>(source: [m-audio.com](http://www.m-audio.com/images/global/product_pics/th/IE_30_custom.jpg))</sub>

The IE30s cost US$250, and the IE40s cost US$450.  For a bit of a cheaper solution with near the same quality, they also make IE10s and IE20s for $100 and $200.  Extremely comfortable, replaceable cable, changeable ear gels / foams, and great sound!

[alt text http://images.guitarcenter.com/products/optionlarge/MAudio/448245.jpg](http://images.guitarcenter.com/products/optionlarge/MAudio/448245.jpg)

Good stuff.  I had an old pair of Shures that I never liked.  Very uncomfortable.  Sounded decent.  I've heard good things about the Klipsche in-ears, but never listened to them.  The best, in my book, are the custom fitted ones.  You can go through Ultimate Ears to get custom molded in-ears.  Crazy nice stuff.  Also crazy expensive...

So, all that being said, I'd go with the M-Audio IE-20xb for you.  US$200, very comfortable, and sounds amazing...

Answer (score 2):

If you're on a budget, I HIGHLY recommend the [Altec Lansing UHP336](http://www.alteclansing.com/?file=north_product_detail&iproduct_id=uhp336) in-ears.  They are [$40 on amazon.com](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B000Q7IA5E) here.  They are rebranded [Ultimate Ears SuperFi 3 Studio](https://web.archive.org/web/20100209000706/http://www.ultimateears.com:80/_ultimateears/store/products/superfi3studio.php) in-ears, which normally sell for [$99 or more on amazon.com](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B000B5XU06).  For the price, you can't beat them.  I've owned the [SuperFi 3's](https://web.archive.org/web/20100209000706/http://www.ultimateears.com:80/_ultimateears/store/products/superfi3studio.php) for a few years now and really enjoyed the full range they have.

[Altec Lansing UHP336 http://www.alteclansing.com/image_na.php?image=uhp336.jpg](http://www.alteclansing.com/?file=north_product_detail&iproduct_id=uhp336)

The only caveat would be the size of the part that goes in your ear canal - it's a little larger in this model than it would be in [Shures](https://web.archive.org/web/20120726032710/http://www.shure.com/europe/products/earphones-headphones/se-models/index.htm).  It will only be a problem if you have extremely tiny ear canals, but I thought I would mention it.

[image: Ultimate Ears SuperFi 3 Studio]

Comment: Gotta say, Iain, I love how you go back and add all the pictures and links.  Thanks for your hard work!

Answer (score 2):

Sennheiser CX-300 if you find other inner-ear headphones intrusive..